# Azure DevOps REST API call to list releases is not working. Any suggestions?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, powerbi, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I am attempting a list all releases for a pipeline in Azure DevOps by using the Azure DevOps REST API. The documentation states that the call to get a release is:

`https://dev.azure.com/(organization)/(project)/_apis/release/releases/(releaseId)?api-version=(version)`

and the call to list all releases is:

`(organization)/(project)/_apis/release/releases?api-version=(version)`

**But the call always fails.** In ADO, I have the release ID, but the path to the releases is pipelines/releases. By this I mean that to get to the list of releases, you must go to the pipeline dropdown, hit releases, select the pipeline, and then it shows the list of releases for that pipeline. I am not too familiar with API's and I am using postman to test these URL calls before using these calls in PowerBI to make a table.

Is there a call to get to the list of these releases? I can get a list of runs by pipeline but not a list of releases.

Comment: *But the call always fails*. Okay. **How** does it fail? What error are you getting? Can you share your code?

Comment: Please take a look at joelforsyth's answer to see if it is helpful to you. If you think it is a solution, please check it as a correct answer for others who meet the same question.

Answer (score 0):

The correct subdomain is `https://vsrm.dev.azure.com` so just change your call to this:
`https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/(organization)/(project)/_apis/release/releases/(releaseId)?api-version=(version)`

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get-release?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)